# Make test cases in a sequence so I can remove multiple Login calls in TestNG

Tags: java, selenium, testng, report, assertion

I'm looking for a way to make test cases in order so I can use login and logout one time.

```
@WebTest
@Test(groups = {"main_feature"} )
public void Check_Home_page () {
    flow.login();  //Inside login() we do assertion to find login was successful
    flow.ValidateProfilePic(); //Inside ValidateProfilePic() we do assertion to find picture section is available
}
```

we will run xml file as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Smoke Result" parallel="false" thread-count="0">
<parameter name="seleniumHub" value="false" />
<parameter name="hubUrl" value="http://someurl:1144/wd/hub" />

<test name="Test Run">
    <parameter name="webPageUrl" value="http://mttesting.com" />
    <parameter name="browser" value="chrome" />
    <groups>
        <run>
            <include name="main_feature" />
        </run>
    </groups>
    <classes>
        <class name="test.HomeTest" />
    </classes>
</test>

<listeners>
    <listener class-name="selenium.DefaultCapability"></listener>
    <listener class-name="selenium.WebCapability"></listener>
    </listeners>
</suite>
```

Once the execution get over in the report `we should` be able to see like

- > Testcases Run : 2, failure : 0 Check_Home_page
- > login(passed)
- > ValidateProfilePic(passed)

Comment: I don't know what you mean? Maybe you share the result you got (including exception stacktrace) and the login respectively the ValidateProfilePic methods. BTW: Please check out the [Java Coding conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use one time login and logout, Simply you can use `priority = 1` for `testHomePage`  and `dependsOnMethods` for `testProfilePicture`. This way you can achieve one time login and logout. Please have a look on below code:

**Test -1 :**

```
@Test(priority = 1, groups = { "main_feature" })
public void testHomePage () {
    flow.login();  //we do assertion to find login was successful
}
```

**Test -2 :**

```
    @Test(dependsOnMethods = { "testHomePage" }, groups = { "main_feature" })
    public void testProfilePicture () {
        flow.ValidateProfilePic(); //we do assertion to find picture section is available

// Call logout function here.
    }
```

I hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The whole idea is to remove multiple login calls. I think i should reconstruct  my test cases, so that the first test case will login and the last one will do a logout.

Comment: Ohhh then you can use priority 1 for login and for profile pic test case use dependsOn with Group. So you don’t need to use login each time. But your question is not mentioning this requirement. I have just edited the answer. Try it and tell me it serves your purpose.

Comment: Looks good to me, if you can update the existing answer with your suggestion, that  should be great. Because the current answer does not serve the newly edited question.

Comment: I updated the answer with approach I have used. Please accept it as answer to help the people in future with same problem.